# apache on centos 5.6 gives me permissions denied error

Tags: php, centos, apache-2.2, configuration

I'm running apache on centos 5.6 and whenever i try to load a php script in any directory, other than /var/www/html (the apache default root dir) it gives me a permissions denied error.

However when i check the permissions of my new root dir (/var/www-dev) against the default dir (/var/www/html), they match identically.  both say: root:root 755

i even tried changing the ownership to apache:apache, and still got the same error

But when i change the apache config back it's default root dir (/var/www/html) everything works.

Am i doing something wrong?

These are the settings i am changing:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note: i am restarting apache every time i change the apache config and permissions.

as well: i also have REMI and EPEL enabled

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: @TiZon i don't believe so. should it be?

Comment: Can you give us the exact message? Is this "permission denied" coming from the file system or directly from apache (e.g. by some Order directive)? And are there messages in the error.log file?

Comment: And check if you have any .htaccess files in those two subdirectories.

Comment: I do have htaccess in those directories. The code in the .htaccess is `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/index.php $1/ [L]` 

However, I think @TiZon was right about the SELinux, it was enabled. I disabled it. rebooted my server and now i can change the apache root dir to another dir with no problem

Comment: The exact error msg in my server log was this: `[Mon May 23 18:35:57 2011] [error] [client 192.168.0.101] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.php denied
`

Comment: Thanks @TiZon! SELinux, was enabled. Once i disabled it editing the /etc/selinux/config file, my web apps were able to load in other directors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually that comes from Selinux not giving access to the folder.
do

```
ls -alZ /var/www/
```

and if the html folder doesn't have the context system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t, fix it with chcon

```
chcon -v -R --type=httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html
```

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: Thanks @Julien Vehent! I'll reward you the answer because your method allows me to edit SELinux permissions on a specific folder rather than disabling SELinux all together. Thank you very much. This worked! and saved me a headache.